# Bootstrap align horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I have all align horizontal the below code renders as shown in the screen 1 and but I'm trying to have as shown in screen 2

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Number</label> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="text" id="number"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">

                </div>

          </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Tag</label> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="text" id="Name"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                </div>

          </div>
    </div>
```

Screen shot 1:
[image]

Screen shot 2:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but your html is incorrect, try replacing `</input>` with `>`.

Comment: its a typo i will edit my question and correct it

Comment: Inputs are self-closing, you don't need a `</input>`. Other than that it seems to work ok? http://www.bootply.com/isTYzlrZNo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML structure is incorrect; you're nesting columns and rows and then columns inside columns for no reason. [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

See example.

(*The columns are **XS** as in your example which in this case will not render very well from a mobile screen, consider using **SM**)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="myForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Number" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Number</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Number" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tag" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Tag</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="tag" /> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```